# Time out for an application in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, timeout

Right now I am developing an application which needs to exit once the application is left idle for some time. Whenever there is no input from touchscreen or trackpad or keypad then the application must abruptly close

Can anyone help me with the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement SystemListener2 to your UiApplication

public class ClassName extends UiApplication implements SystemListener2

one of the implemented method "backlightStateChange(boolean on)"

```
public boolean check;
public void backlightStateChange(boolean on) {
    check = true;
    if (on == false) { //on idle
        long idlestart = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long endtime = idlestart + 50000; //5mins wait to exit
        while (check) {
            if (endtime < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    } else {
        check = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the SystemListener2 event handlers are called from the UI event handling thread.   That means you don't want to sleep in the handler - it will block all other application UI elements from responding, and likely cause your app to be terminated by the OS.